# Matlab sum computation

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I'm writing a linear regression assignment in Matlab (y-intercept fixed in the origin). I need to update my value of slope in each iteration step. N is the number of my data points. I did it like this inside a for loop:

```
for i = 1:numIter
   sum = 0;
   for i = 1:n
      sum = sum + (slope*x(i) - y(i))*x
   end
slope = slope - factor*sum;
end
```

My program returns the wrong results with error of a few percent and after running test cases, I concluded that the single iteration step is doing the wrong thing. Am I missing something obvious? I'm new to numerical computations in Matlab.

Thank you for any input.

Edit. 
What runs is this

```
data = load('data.txt');
x = [data(:,1)];
y = [data(:,2)];
slope = 0;
iter = 1000; %number of iterations
factor = 0.1/n; %rate at which we approach the optimum
slope = fit(x, y, slope, factor, iter);
```

The function is in another file and it looks like this:

```
function slope = fit(x, y, slope, factor, iter)
n = length (x);
for i = 1:iter
   sum = 0;
      for j = 1:n
         sum = sum + (slope*x(j) - y(j))*x(j)
         % we were given such a formula
      end
   slope = slope - factor*sum;
end
end
```

I wonder if I slipped somewhere around interations.

Edit2. Equation to update the slope (S).

S_i+1 = S_i - rate/n  sum _j=1 ^n [ ( S_i*x_j - y_j)*S_i ]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. What is n, what is factor and what is the initial value of slope? Could you share a code that I can run on my computer?

Comment: I just edited to account for your questions.

Comment: Ok, first of you are using a reserved name for you function, because `fit` is a built-in function in MATLAB so you should change it.

Comment: I changed names to post the question here to not cause any plagiarism suspicion, so the name is different (not 'fit'). Of course, I'm not going to copy anyone else's answers or get anyone do this for me, I just need someone else's fresh look at this, because when I check with the lecture notes which give the algorithm how to do this, everything seems to be fine and I must have made an ommission or confused variables. To hell with cheaters, they make everything difficult for those who really want to learn.

Comment: I tried your code, I tried it with `x` and `y` of a line with a slope that is equal to 1. I had to tweak the parameter `factor` and `iter` to obtain the correct solution. Try that. Otherwise post the pseudo code of the algorithm from the lecture note.

Comment: Okay. Then I'll try what the change in the coefficient and number of iterations does. I'm sticking the equation in the original post.

Comment: `sum` is also the name of a built-in function. Try to choose longer names for your variables like `sum_in_iteration`. actually by using the `sum` function you could get rid of the `for j`loop (which is always a good thing): `sum_in_iteration = sum(slope*x - y).*x)`. Please note that there has to be a dot at the last multiplication sign